# Courses closely following Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation

I am self-studying Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, and for now, my goal is to work through the first two chapters - Abstract Integration and Positive Borel Measures. I am required by my supervisor (I am an undergraduate mathematics major, by the way) to learn from this book - but I find the exposition very terse, and sometimes it takes an hour to figure out the stuff on one page. I know that math demands time and effort, I am not shying away from that, I'm just looking for any course material online (lecture notes, slides, videos, problem sets, etc.) that could effectively **supplement** my reading of this text, and make my journey somewhat *easier*.

Could you please help me out by suggesting any courses (in the form of videos, lecture notes/slides, problem sets, etc.) that could supplement my reading and make the job of understanding Rudin easier?

If not, then it would be good to know of any other books that closely follow the content in Rudin but are *easier to understand*. Anyway, Rudin intended the book to be a text for graduate students - and as an undergraduate student, I guess I could use some help. Thanks a lot!

---

To summarize the recommendations I've gotten so far:

- Gerald Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*.
- Sheldon Axler's *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis*.

Comment: Yeah I guess this isn't a duplicate like I first thought. Why don't you *also* ask your lecturer/supervisor this question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I shall try to do that. Meanwhile, it will be helpful if the folks at MSE could throw some light on this!

Comment: Folland is more accessible. It would be a good entry point. I prefer Folland anyway. I'm not a big fan of Rudin. His texts feel too old fashioned for me and don't quite capture the way people think about those subjects today in my opinion.

Comment: Actually, that you are spending an hour on each page sounds like you're doing it right.

Comment: Agreed, @LeeMosher. However, it'd still be nice to know if anything could help make this text more accessible!

Comment: You might want to try Measure, Integration & Real Analysis, whose electronic version is legally free to the world at https://measure.axler.net/.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @SheldonAxler! I have read your Linear Algebra book, which is by far the most beautiful text on the topic I have ever seen. Looking forward to reading this one!